# I wrote a C code for solving heat equation, but at the execution it says "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".so can someone help me with this?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<math.h>

#define L 10

#define T 10

#define Kmax 1000

#define N 1000

#define cond 0.25

int main() {    
    int i,j;

    float dt,dx,b;

    float x[i],t[j],u[i][j];        b=2*cond*dt/(dx*dx);    
    for(i=1;i<=N+1;i++)     {       x[i]=i*dx;

        u[i][T]=1;  }   for(j=1;j<=Kmax+1;j++)  {       t[j]=j*dt;

        u[L][j]=0;

        u[N+1][j]=0;

        t[j]=(j)*dt;    }   for(j=1;j<Kmax;j++)         {       for(i=2;i<N;i++)            {

            u[i][j+1]=u[i][j]+0.5*b*(u[i-1][j]+u[i+1][j]-2*u[i][j]);
                        printf("%7.4f\t",u[i][j]);


-----

        printf("\n");       }   } }
```

Comment: Wow!  That's some crazy indentation style!

Comment: Please compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`), improve your code to have no warnings, then **use the debugger** (`gdb`); your "fix my code" question is off-topic here.

Comment: If you expect anyone to read this mess, you need to fix the indention and adopt a conventional coding style.

Comment: sorry for the whole mess

Answer (score 3):

```
b=2*cond*dt/(dx*dx);
```

Variables `dt` and `dx` are uninitialized and using uninitialized variables leads to undefined behavior.

You have a VLA based on variables `i` and `j` and they are uninitialized too.
Since `i` and `j` are uninitialized and you are using them to create an array looks like the value of `i` and `j` is some hugh value and there is no enough stack memory to allocate that array and you are seeing a crash.

Comment: Yes. There are even more uninitialised variables, even the VLA dimensions `i` and `j`. I guess that is where the seg fault comes from.

Comment: @MOehm Yes you are right added that to my answer